# Sort and sum up the values of a column according to another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to make an sql query where it sorts a table, groups up the states as well as add up the visit count.

| States | Visit Count |
| --- | --- |
| Ohio | 4 |
| Arizona | 3 |
| Ohio | 2 |
| Arizona | 1 |

This is a simplified version of my sql queries as a whole, as I had multiple clients making bookings to accomodations and facilities, all of which are in varying states.

I have seen the question that asks about choosing a specific row based on its value and calculate values on the row's other columns, but I would like to sort all of the rows.

This is the result I expect:

| States | Visit Count |
| --- | --- |
| Ohio | 6 |
| Arizona | 4 |

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, SUM().

Comment: This is a *very* basic SQL requirement, you need to read some tutorials on [aggregates and grouping](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-sum-with-group-by.php)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below

```
select sum(visit count) as [visit Count],States
from tableName group by States
order by sum(visit count) desc
```

Comment: `visit count` is not a valid column name. `[visit Count]` is not a valid alias name in MySQL. And as the OP seems to be completely unfamiliar with aggregation, you should explain what your query does in detail, rather than just posting the mere query. Stu's recommendation in the request comments is on point: The OP should read a SQL tutorial instead of coming here and filing this as a request. (Stu's link to some would-be tutorial, however, is nothing that I would recommend, though.)